# access local http server with a name

Tags: server, apache2

I set up an http server and a WLAN access point on a Raspberry Pi. The idea is do let people walk by, log into the network with their smartphones and access a web page with information. I got it working to the point where you have to type 192.168.0.1 into your browser after connecting. I wanted to change this to "test1.test2" or "test1.test2.test3" and tried various tutorials on bind9. It did not work out. Don't know how to debug the settings I did, syntax seems to be correct. Is it the wrong tool for this? Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: bind9 is a correct tool for what you want. It is what I use. There might be other ways, I don't know. As a reference, I recommend the [Ubuntu serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will go check as soon as I have the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to get anyone connected to your router to access `192.168.0.1` via `test1.test2.test3` then it will be router dependent and it would have nothing to do with Ubuntu.

In that case you would need to edit your router's `hosts` file.

For instance, if you were running **OpenWRT** on your router, you would edit `/etc/hosts` and you would add:

```
192.168.0.1 test1.test2.test3
```

and then you would run the following command:

```
/etc/init.d/network restart
```

Then anyone that connects to your router and types "test1.test2.test3" in the URL bar of their web browser, it will be taken to your web server running on: `192.168.0.1`.

The logic is the same for other routers too but there may be a different way of doing the same thing. For instance, you may need to do it over the web interface.

However it will have to do with Ubuntu if you edit your hosts file in Ubuntu `/etc/hosts` and then anyone using "your" PC will be able to access 192.168.0.1 when typing test1.test2.test3. A restart of your PC will be required if you don't restart the network service.

Comment: To clarify, there is no router involved. I am using hostapd.

Comment: I see, I haven't used hostapd before, but what I have shown above is at least one of way of doing it and I know it works. I hope someone else will be able to help.